# Making a qustom EnumChatFormatting Color

Tags: java, minecraft

Is there a way to make a custom color with EnumChatFormatting, with rgb or hsb? Because i got a gui where i can change the menu color with red(0-255), blue, green also. Now i got the problem to insert that values to EnumChatFormatting anyone got a solution?

Comment: doubt it, that enum just holds the constants you also find here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes For example `EnumChatFormatting.DARK_RED` should give you `§4` but that's not customizable to rgb or hsb color codes since it's just a single letter code for a few predefined colors and styles.

Comment: is there a other way to format a text with custom hsb or rgb

Answer (score 0):

It depends. So if you're making a forge mod, it's possible to set the color of your custom GUIs to whatever you want. The `ChatFormatting` enum is already used in minecrafts code, so you can't change that easily.

Comment: can you please explain more your answer ?

Comment: You can't add any ChatFormatting enums. It would also require heavy changes to minecrafts code in order to add a new color to the chat.